# Jasypt not able to encrypt exponential power (^) symbol in password

Tags: jasypt

I am trying to encrypt the following password `my^Password` using below:

```
.\encrypt.bat input=j!p^RVKvt3LaHw37 "password=<my_salt>" "algorithm=PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC" providerClassName=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

When I decrypt the encrypted string, The exponent sign `^` is gone. I've also noticed this issue with some other symbols.

```
.\decrypt.bat 'input=<encrypted-string>' "password=<my_salt>" "algorithm=PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC" providerClassName=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Output:
`myPassword`

Can anyone help fix this issue? I've scorched the internet but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that windows powershell has a bug where it can’t properly encode a password with special characters. I performed the exact same commands on command prompt and it worked like a charm.